# Error: client_secrets.json issue when running a HTTP Azure Function

Tags: azure, .net-core, google-api, youtube-api, azure-functions

I have created this HTTP trigger azure function, which contains the code(below) to upload a video to YouTube automatically. Source: (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert).

When I try to run the app, I am getting the following error:

> Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=84400f0c-b6e4-4c78-bf55-30c4527a8b5f)
>   System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1.
>   System.Private.CoreLib: Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\TestDemo\UploadVideo\UploadVideo\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\client_secrets.json'.

It looks like a Google Authentication error, but I am not sure how to get this fixed.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.Threading;

namespace UploadVideo
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            log.LogInformation("YouTube Data API: Upload Video");
            log.LogInformation("==============================");

            try
            {
                await Run();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    log.LogInformation("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
            }

            return new OkObjectResult($"Video Processed..");

        }

        private static async Task Run()
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                    // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None
                );
            }

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });

            var video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
            video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"
            var filePath = @"C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\audio\Test.mp4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
                videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

                await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
            }
        }

        private static void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
        {
            switch (progress.Status)
            {
                case UploadStatus.Uploading:
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
                    break;

                case UploadStatus.Failed:
                    Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private static void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error cause the `client_secrets.json` doesn't exist in the debug folder. I reproduce the error with this file default setting `Copy to Output Directory`, the default is Do not copy.

[image]

So just change it to `Copy if newer` or `Copy always`, the file will be in the debug folder.

[image]

Comment: Any update now? If this could help you, you could accept it as the answer.

Comment: I am not seeing secrets.json in my solution explorer. I only see host.json and local.settings.json. Did you manually create the secets.json file?

Comment: Yes, how did you create the file?

Comment: I created the client_secrets.json file and put it in the same directory. However, when I run the code now, I am seeing this error:
Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=4ca291c2-cfab-4ad6-8a39-c8afcb83603c)
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. Google.Apis.Auth: At least one client secrets (Installed or Web) should be set.

Did you also get the same error when you ran it? Also my client_secrets.json file is empty after running the function.

Comment: I did not test with google api, I just try to let you know what your problem is, and in my file it's just simple json data, also my file is not empty in the debug folder.

Comment: @Peter, suppose this could help you, could you accept it as the answer to close this question.